# checkbox en un formulario no se puede interactuar con el

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Hola estoy intentando agregar un checkbox a mi formulario de registro, he probado varias configuraciones y creo que puede ser un tema de estilos, parece que algo estuviera superpuesto sobre el checkbox y no me permite interactuar con el.

```css
input, select, textarea {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

#registro input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="registro">
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row gtr-uniform">
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="nombre" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" placeholder="Nomnbre" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Contraseña" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" value="" placeholder="Repite tu Contraseña" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" value="" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento" />
      </div>
      <!-- Desplegables con region, provincia y comuna -->
      <!-- Listas desplegables -->
      <select id="regiones" name="regiones">
      </select>
      <select id="provincias" disabled>
      </select>
      <select id="comunas" disabled>
      </select>
      <!-- Botón de Acceso -->
      <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="actions special">
          <li><input type="submit" value="Registrate" class="primary" /></li>
          <li><input type="reset" value="Limpiar" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="acepta_politicas" name="acepta_politicas" required>
      <label for="acepta_politicas">Acepto las <a href="#" target="_blank">políticas de privacidad y de uso</a> del sitio web.</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

este es mi formulario y este es el css del checkbox

el checkbox se ve pero no puedo marcarlo, se agradece cualquier ayuda!

Comment: que checkbox?? el se aceptar?? aca funciona ;)

Comment: Si, pero con el css en el sitio web no funciona, y no se porque

Comment: claro.. pero aca, no podemos hacer magia y reproducir un problema que no estas mostrando... ;) por lo pronto, lo que mostras funciona.. hay algo en otro lado...

Comment: @Rodrigo en tu página web, donde ves el fallo, pulsa con el botón derecho sobre el checkbox y dale a inspeccionar elemento. Cuando se abra la consola de desarrollador, mira los estilos que se están aplicando al checkbox, tienen que aparecer los estilos que estás dando y algo más. Puede incluso que no aparezcan tus estilos y que sean los estilo de otro elemento que está tapando el checkbox (¿es por eso por lo que añadías el `z-index`?)

Comment: Pon la susodicha web y la reviso.

Comment: @OCHOA todo el contenido necesario para resolver el problema debe estar contenido en la publicación. Añadir enlaces a sitios externos puede ayudar al usuario a corto plazo, pero no ayuda a otros miembros de la comunidad que pueden tener el mismo problema (ahora o en el futuro). Esto es porque en cuanto se solucione el problema, en enlace deja de servir de referencia.

Comment: @OCHOA Hola ... tengo la web en modo de prueba y puede verse aquí https://laolla-42a84.web.app/reg.html

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro efectivamente el z-index lo agregue por esa razon, pero aun asi no parece funcionar

Comment: @Rodrigo he traído los estilos que afectan al checkbox. Tienes un `appearance: none` en main.css que es lo que causa todo (y que no habías puesto en la pregunta). Ahora ya se puede reproducir el problema aquí. ¿Por qué pones ese estilo?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro entiendo pero si reviso la web, veo que pasa, luego respondo diciendo que pasa y como resolverlo (que es lo que siempre hago) entonces la respuesta si sirve a futuro aunque el link desaparezca. Muchas veces he hecho lo mismo y al final digo el problema, la solución y si puedo un pequeño snippet para recrear el problema/solución y todo nice. Pero lo tomaré en cuenta siempre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en tu main.css que tienes los siguientes estilos:

```css
input, select, textarea {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Con esa regla estás haciendo que los input, select y textarea no tengan la apariencia que tienen por defecto y se puedan dar estilos de forma más sencilla.

Todo correcto hasta ahí. Y defines tus propios estilos para el checkbox:

```css
#registro input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Entonces, ¿cuál es el problema? ¡Que **no estás definiendo estilos para cuando el checkbox esté marcado**! Entonces, aunque el checkbox está marcado, se sigue ver sin marcar... ¡pero está marcado!

La solución: añade estilos para cuando el checkbox esté marcado. Esto se puede hacer con la pseudo-clase `:checked`:

```css
#registro input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  /* estilos para cuando el checkbox esté marcado */
}
```

Aquí puedes verlo aplicado a la demo compartida en la pregunta:

```css
input, select, textarea {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

#registro input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#registro input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: #369;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="registro">
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row gtr-uniform">
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="nombre" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" placeholder="Nomnbre" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Contraseña" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" value="" placeholder="Repite tu Contraseña" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
        <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" value="" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento" />
      </div>
      <!-- Desplegables con region, provincia y comuna -->
      <!-- Listas desplegables -->
      <select id="regiones" name="regiones">
      </select>
      <select id="provincias" disabled>
      </select>
      <select id="comunas" disabled>
      </select>
      <!-- Botón de Acceso -->
      <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="actions special">
          <li><input type="submit" value="Registrate" class="primary" /></li>
          <li><input type="reset" value="Limpiar" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="acepta_politicas" name="acepta_politicas" required>
      <label for="acepta_politicas">Acepto las <a href="#" target="_blank">políticas de privacidad y de uso</a> del sitio web.</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente explicación, muchas gracias! se soluciono el problema! ...